# WEBRTC MediaRecorder on HDMI feed records large files in some machines

Tags: javascript, webrtc

The incoming HDMI feed is 1920x1280.  We make a stream 640x480 like (with frameRate 20 and maxwidth 720):

```
var constraints = {
      audio: {deviceId: audiosrc ? {exact: audiosrc} : undefined},
      video: {deviceId: videosrc ? {exact: videosrc} : undefined,
        frameRate: {
          max: frameRate
        },
        width: {
            max: maxwidth
        }
      }
    
    };
    
    this.AVStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
options = {mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9',videoBitsPerSecond: this.bitRate};
this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.AVStream, options);
```

We make a media recorder to record vp9 with this stream and 500kbits/s.
When we run this setup in our office on chrome everything works fine.  The media recorder records at 500kbits/s and we get files that come out about 4mb/min.
When we run this same setup in hospitals on chrome the mediarecorder doesn't pay attention to the bitrate we set.  The mediarecorder object shows 500kbits, but the recordings that come out have a video bit rate of up to 3.5megabits/s.

```
MediaRecorder {stream: MediaStream, mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9", state: "recording", onstart: null, onstop: ƒ, …}
audioBitsPerSecond: 0
mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus"
ondataavailable: n=> {…}
onerror: null
onpause: null
onresume: null
onstart: null
onstop: n=>{console.log("Recorder stopped: ",n)}
state: "inactive"
stream: MediaStream {id: "UbJM4Nh4dOq6bqssHxF74907E4o48oj6A3SD", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null, …}
videoBitsPerSecond: 500000
```

In some rooms the bitrate of the recording that comes out is better and in some it's worse.  This happens in 2 different hospitals.  I noticed that the version of chrome in the hospitals is an organization managed 32bit version.

Any ideas what could cause the mediarecorder to ignore the bitrate?

Answer (score 0):

As strange as it is for something so widely used not to work properly, it seems this is the case with webrtc mediarecorder using vp9 in chrome.  We have a high definition feed coming from ultrasound machines and whatever we set the bitrate to did not limit the size of the recordings.  I saw this post https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=605750 from a few years ago where they said that vp9 takes kilobits and not bits for recording.  I tried setting 500 as the bits per second.  Chrome gave a clamp warning and raised the bitrate to the minimum 100000 bits per second.  In the end the recording vp9 really was 100kbits per second.  The problem for us is that the quality is not good at 100kbits/sec and we can't find a way to set it for vp9.
I tried h264 over the same exact HDMI feed (I replayed the same recording) and set the bit rate to 600000 (600kbits/sec) and lo and behold the recording actually came out at 600kbits/sec.